# Reference VBA to run a macro from a workbook whose name is specified in a cell range & compile error in hidden module error

Tags: excel, vba

So i have been trying to run a procedure that exists in Workbook A.xlsm i.e Test_v1.1 from another macro in workbook B.xlsm. I have 2 questions.

1> Workbook A.xlsm i.e Test_v1.1 keeps changing the version number of the
  file hence i have referenced the workbook name in cell "A2" in Workbook 
  B.xlsm i am successful in opening the workbook based on the cell reference 
  but unable to run the procedure. Need to how to reference the workbook name 
  in a cell when i'm using "Application.run" command

2> When i use Application.run an "compile error in hidden module module 3 " 
   occurs. How can i overcome this. to keep you posted  the modules in 
   Test_v1.1 in  password protected and the macro it self has additional 
   references i.e Access etc, which workbook B.xlsm does not  have.

```
Sub extract_data()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Excel.Application.EnableEvents = False

Test_ver = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Value

Dim sdate As Date
Dim edate As Date
Dim test_wb As Workbook
Dim test_ws As Worksheet
Set test_wb = Workbooks.Open("'path" & Test_ver)
Set test_ws = test_wb.Worksheets(1)

sdate = Date - 1
ydate = Date

test_ws.DTPicker1.Value = sdate
test_ws.DTPicker2.Value = edate

' Run procedure on Test macro  --------------------------------------------> Need help here

Application.Run "Test_v1.1.xlsm!Button1_Click"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.CutCopyMode = True

Excel.Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Compile error :

> "compile error in hidden module module 3 "

is what i'm getting

Comment: Not sure, but is the Macro in a Module? Also I would probably write the workbook name like : `Application.Run "'Test_v1.1.xlsm'!Button1_Click"` with the single speech marks...

Comment: @Mikku Thank you for your response. Yes. The macro is in the module for both Test_v1.1.xlsm and workbook B.xlsm. i do agree with the code. But however workbook name "Test_v1.1" keeps changing. hence i have provided the name in a cell reference. how do i refer this cell value as workbook in application.run command.? and i'm getting a compiler error : compile error in hidden module module 3  when i'm doing it.

Comment: @Xabier ..  The upper comment is meant for you :)

Comment: @Xabier : Sorry my bad. its for you.

Comment: Change this `Application.Run "Test_v1.1.xlsm!Button1_Click"` to `Application.Run "'" & test_wb.Name & "'!Button1_Click"` .. You have to add `'` this before and after the name of the Workbook

Comment: @Mikku Will definitely try it out tomorrow and post my response here. What about the "i'm getting a compiler error : compile error in hidden module module 3 ". Since the test_v1.1.xlsm does have VBA references to Ms access and the modules here are protected. Is there a way to bypass this ? If not is there a way to simply click the command button in test_v1.1.xlsm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

- You need to add `'` before and after the name of the Workbook while calling the Macro

**So change**

```
Application.Run "Test_v1.1.xlsm!Button1_Click"
```

**To:**

```
Application.Run "'" & test_wb.Name & "'!Button1_Click"
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: adds.xlsm workbook name changes then will this still work ?

Comment: Yes It will. It is picking name from the Cell.